# Merging a question with itself removes the ability to answer and comment

Tags: bug, status-completed, moderation, merged-questions

See [Mootools events, callable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3259145/mootools-events-callable)

Merging a question with itself probably shouldn't be possible.  I tried rolling back to the original version, but that had no effect.

Comment: Argh, my head's spinning from the testing...

Comment: @Andy: Imagine how long it took me to figure out what the problem was!  ;)

Comment: @Popular Demand: There was a mod flag on that question asking for a tag merge.  The wording might have been a little confusing, leading @Will to merge the question to itself.  Either that, or idle curiosity would be my other guess.  @Will wouldn't be the first one to experiment with the mod tools.  :)

Comment: @Pop: Now they think about putting it before the name ...

Comment: @Bill: Are you able to manually unlock the question?

Comment: @Jon Seigel: Well now I just feel silly!  Thanks.  :)

Comment: @Bill: You're welcome. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ah, OK -- we checked in a change that prevents self-merges.

Comment: Oh, darn... sorry about the time spent on this one.  It didn't occur to me that merging and locking were so closely intertwined.

Answer (score 1):

I guess `[status-by-design]` is the best fit for this one.  This is really a non-issue since the action is easily reversed by manually unlocking the question, as suggested by @Jon Seigel in the comments.  Thanks Jon.