# Broken Questions?

Tags: bug, status-completed, questions, meta

It seems that some questions are breaking down on Meta. Including this very question itself, the following three I have experienced issues with.

- [Undeserved Organizer badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57380/undeserved-organizer-badge)
- [Merging a question with itself removes the ability to answer and comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57388/merging-a-question-with-itself-removes-the-ability-to-answer-and-comment)
- [Concerted Efforts to Close "Hidden Features of X Language" Type of Question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57363/concerted-efforts-to-close-hidden-features-of-x-language-type-of-question) (This one used to be fine, but after the latest edit it has joined the crew of broken posts)

Half the time I try to view them, I get an "Oops, something bad has happened". Sometimes I get through, sometimes I don't. Any activity is going to just trigger yet another chance for the error page. And it seems like I'm not the only one, which is a relief.

Something I *am* noticing in common with all of these questions. Not something they have in common themselves, but something in common with when you can actually see them. When I can see these questions, I never see a "Related" list. Only the "Linked" section. I can see the "Related" section fine on other questions, but these questions only display for me when "Related" is not displayed. Anyone else noticing this?

Comment: yeah it's broken for me too.  I was getting the same error when trying to access [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57388/merging-a-question-with-itself-removes-the-ability-to-answer-and-comment), but I think that might have just been Bill the Lizard doing some testing.

Comment: I'm seeing the "Oops, something bad happened happened" a lot today, usually just after editing.

Comment: Actually, in review, it's no longer just that question. Many of the recent questions seem to be breaking too (including this question). I think a better report is needed to be called for. Shall I revise this into a more comprehensive report?

Comment: It's also happening on *this question right here*.

Comment: @Grace: Do you just want to edit this one to a more general bug report?  (If you can...)

Comment: I got it with *this* question. I edited the URL form another question by hand to get here. And Billy, our lizard friend, is posting duplicates. I guess not intentionally. Jeff, FIX THIS!

Comment: @Bill Revised. If you manage to see it.

Comment: @Ladybug: Yes, it was this same problem that caused the double-post.  I was hoping nobody would see that. :)

Comment: No lizard escapes my eyes, @Bill ;)

Comment: Yep - got the "Something bad happened" page the first time I tried to view this very question.

Comment: Yes, experienced as an intermittent problem, including on this very page about 10 minutes ago.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We had a slight issue in the build process - this has been resolved.

Comment: Thank you much, Geoff! Glad it is all over.