# Show related questions immediately after posting

Tags: feature-request, duplicate-questions, related-questions, caching

See: [Why does the Related question list not always show up?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65582/why-does-the-related-question-list-not-always-show-up)

The answer there states that it is an expensive query to run, so it's not done immediately. I remember reading somewhere else that due to increased importance, it is run often while asking questions.

However, right after asking, a question is likely to get attention, and be closed as a duplicate. The problem is, the related list isn't showing, so someone has to go search for a duplicate. When they come back, someone has already posted an answer, leading to noise on the site.

**My suggestion**: Either:

1. Cache the final "related questions" list from the ask dialog to use for the first 15 minutes
2. Run the query right away.

EDIT (12/11/14): Was this changed? I just saw a related list on a question 1 minute old.

Comment: Inspired by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26735059/make-use-of-character-in-json-object