# "Related questions" section not showing up on new questions

Tags: bug, status-completed, related-questions

I noticed the "Related Questions" list did not show up on questions asked today. On older questions, it is shown, however. On this meta site, the last question having this list was asked 17 hours ago.

I made some research and have seen those posts:

- [Why does the Related question list not always show up?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65582/why-does-the-related-question-list-not-always-show-up): this post explains that the query taking care of this is not run often because it is expensive. But *17 hours*?
- [Show related questions immediately after posting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/243035/show-related-questions-immediately-after-posting): I fully agree to what is said there and this suggestion was actually the aim of my post, but it is confusing because the edit at the end seems to indicate the system now does it immediately after posting. Which clearly wasn't the case today.

Is it broken? This "related" section is very useful on new posts, to check for dupes. I often checked it and it never occured to me it was missing before.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Our [Elasticsearch setup fell over last night](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/338265/105971) and it took a while to sort it out. Indexing related questions is a pretty intensive operation, so we disabled it while fixing everything else.

It looks like we're good now, so indexing has been turned back on and we're keeping an eye on it.

Comment: [Ping](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/352855/282094).