# Related Questions are not being added to new questions anymore, network wide

Tags: bug, related-questions

Questions all around the network do not get Related Questions anymore, for several hours.

Examples from around the network:

- [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52960945/how-do-i-find-the-publish-path-for-a-uwp-project)
- [Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/340051/what-stats-can-be-determined-prior-to-trapping-a-ghost)
- [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/317193/character-overflow-on-profile-page-with-long-usernames)

This is not a duplicate of [Why does the Related question list not always show up?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65582/why-does-the-related-question-list-not-always-show-up) since that explains the normal caching that causes them to not initially show up until a few minutes (or at most an hour) later; these examples are all a few hours old and the related questions still haven't shown up, so it's clearly a bug.

Can this please be fixed?

Comment: Voting to reopen. There appears to be a bit of a hitch with it; I asked a question many hours ago and it still hasn't shown up; it used to show up within an hour of my asking, if not a few minutes later. (cc @Shadow)

Comment: @Sonic you're correct, it's on all sites. No bug hammer, but added my vote.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

We temporarily disabled this job last night after some changes to the Elastic search configuration. The people working on it didn't want to re-enable it at the end of the day with nobody around to keep an eye on it, so that was postponed and will probably happen later today.

There is a message in our internal chat to the tune of "the users probably won't even notice" – you sure did prove that wrong :)

Comment: People around here have very keen eyes when it comes to their cheese. Move it a bit or take it away and they're sure to notice. So, what changes were made to the search? Any new cool features added? :-)

Comment: Well, to be clear, I was the one who suspected something amiss...most users initially just chalked this up to the job queue and the author agreed (marking this as a dupe).

Comment: And it's back now. Thanks!